# Ordered List (ol) showing up un-numbered?

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list (ol) on my page but the numbering is not showing up at all! I have done this:

```
<ol>
<li>my text</li>
<li>my text</li>
<li>my text</li>
</ol>
```

As I have typed the above, stackoverflow was able to render it correctly the way I wanted it to, like so:

> 1. my text
> 2. my text
> 3. my text

However, this is not happening on my webpage. I am viewing this in Firefox on my localhost.

If any knows why my ol's look like ul's (i.e. no numbering) I would be grateful for help. If not, please let me know how I can achieve a numbered list using ul's.

Thanks all

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's going to be a CSS issue. CSS can change the numbering/bullet style, and even turn it off altogether. Using Firebug, inspect the element and look at the CSS styles on the right to see what styles are being applied to it. Look for one called `list-style`.

Comment: I have used firebug to have a look at any properties it inherits but they are not things that can affect the ol! I have looked for `list-style` especially but nothing! :(

Comment: Ah, I found it. I was only looking for styles of ol/ul not the li themselves! Thanks nickf!

Comment: the `li` should be set to `display: list-item;`

Answer (score 37):

While the `list-style-type` is most likely the problem, especially if you've used a reset stylesheet, you might also make sure that the `margin-left`/`padding-left` of the list is large enough that the numbers can fit into the space.

Also, it might be worth adding `list-style-position: inside;` just to see if the numbers are being generated/applied by the browser.

Comment: Bang on! Spent a while scratching my head over this. Didn't have enough padding.

Answer (score 32):

Very weird situation, the numbers and bullets for my `ol` and `ul` display in Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.  They did not display in any type of browser.  The website is wrapped with a  that has a display:block for the entire website.  I had to enter the below CSS to get the numbers and bullets to display.

```
li {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: This worked to show the numbers, but killed the `inline-block`, 
`float: left;` does allow for both effects though.

Answer (score 27):

Try `list-style-type: decimal;` in your CSS for the `ol`.

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_list.asp) some more values you can use.

Answer (score 21):

If you are using a reset stylesheet, you can enable numbering via css.

```css
ol li {
    list-style: decimal;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Ok, I had the same problem and all I did is set in the LI definition 'display: list-item;'.  This had been overriden to 'display: block;' elsewhere.

I also changed list-style-position from inside to outside so that it'd be in the format I wanted.

Comment: Items styled as a "List" need their display property set to "list-item" per the W3C CSS3 spec. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6257085/3191708

Answer (score 8):

Recently I had the same issue in Firefox 6.

This css code prevented the numbers from showing up:

```
ol li {
  display:block;
}
```

Removing "display:block" revealed them!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the `li` has `display: list-item;`

It's really easy for list items to inherit display block from somewhere which will remove the numbers or bullets

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap seems to have this default style:

```
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

You should override this to remove display: block and move the position to inside:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    list-style-position: inside;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use:

```
*{
padding: 0;
}
```

Turn it off! In my case it was a problem.

Comment: thanks this was a help for me. as i was struggling to find an was was the issue and find out that i am setting this as global style.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks man Really appreciate for this answer I add wrong tag in CSS file, now working fine error due to wrong css tags. My Website [tendtoread.com](http://www.tendtoread.com) If you still face any problem you can inspect element and add this code below. I m using wordpress version.

```
.entry ol ul li, .entry ol li {
    list-style: decimal;
    font-family: initial;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Style family must be in decimal form.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, turns out I simply hadn't closed a `<div>` Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this issue. Very strange.

If I disable:

```
ol li {overflow: hidden;}
```

the numbers pop up.

Otherwise they all sit showing 0 as their number.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly another possible in answer:

removing padding can fix the numbers not showing up.This worked for me in Chrome, not sure if it is the same in other browsers

Answer (score 0):

In my case **display:inline** was overriding the display of the numbers. Perhaps there was an assumption when writing the CSS spec that nobody would want to number items in text that flows like a paragraph. But in the "legal fine print" kind of text I was styling this kind of numbering was exactly what I needed.

The solution was to **float:left** on the **li**

```
ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
ol li {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 4px;
    float:left;
}
```

The padding-left is optional, but it counter-balances the space on the right of the number.

Found the float solution [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?604598-Inline-Ordered-List-with-Numbers-or-Letters).

Answer (score 0):

I had set "overflow: hidden" in root html, which was resulting in disappearance of numbering of list items.
I too had "li" nested in "ol".
Following setting worked (I was using sass):

```
ol {
    overflow: visible;
}
    li {
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A margin/padding reset can also cause numbers to not display. The `<li>` elements inside `<ol>` are a bit indented to the right. This is mimicked via padding natively, which gets reset by the margin/padding reset.

On your `<ol>` element, give `padding: revert` style, which will revert the padding to the original value, as intended for `<ol>` elements.