# How to create an ordered numbered list in React

Tags: reactjs

I need to create an ordered list in `React` and I am doing following in the render()

```
render() {
    <div key ={category.index}>
        question.map(questionlist =>
        <li key={questionlist.key}>{questionlist.description}</li>)}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: What is the question? There is no question here. There are many possible interpretations as demonstrated by the many different answers (some now deleted). Either you are looking for `<ol>` OR you are looking for `question.sort` OR maybe you just want to fix your syntax errors (missing {} around javascript inside jsx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an [ordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) to get the numbering

```
render() {
  <ol>
     {question.map(questionlist =>
       <li key={questionlist.key}>{questionlist.description}</li>
     )}
  </ol>
}
```

Comment: So I am doing `<div key ={category.index}>
         question.map(questionlist =>
         <ol><li key={questionlist.key}>{questionlist.description}</li></ol>)}
      </div>`  _italic_ but the list starts with 1 for all the questions

Comment: Copy and paste my answer. You put the `ol` in the wrong place. You made each list item its own list. You want one list with many items. You need to change the `div` to an `ol`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use curly braces `{}` if you want to use JavaScript inside your JSX.
Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/RGjLyd

Based on your question, I've assumed that your array has the following format:

```
const questionList = [
  {description: 'How to render list in React?', key: 0},
  {description: 'Do you like JS?', key: 1},
  {description: 'Do you know CSS?', key: 2}
];
```

Full code here:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const questionList = [
      {description: 'How to render list in React?', key: 0},
      {description: 'Do you like JS?', key: 1},
      {description: 'Do you know CSS?', key: 2}
    ];

    return (
      <ol>
        {questionList.map(question => {
          return (
            <li key={question.key}>{question.description}</li>
          );
        })}
      </ol>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: He's asking for an ordered list, so it should probably be `ol` instead of `ul`.

Comment: How can I create the

Comment: How can I have  1.One 2.Two 3.Three

Comment: Just modified the answer so that the list is ordered (numbered).

Answer (score 1):

If you are still unable to render an ordered list even after wrapping your JSX `li` elements in an `ol`, [several people have run into lurking `list-style` CSS attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642067/ordered-list-ol-showing-up-un-numbered) (e.g. found in a reset stylesheet) that modify the expected behavior for cross-browser compatibility.

I would inspect the DOM in the browser to double check that that is not the case for you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30589141)